# Setting encoding - Write-Host - Powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I just want to set encoding for the 'Write-Host' command in powershell, version 2.0, but there is no option available. How to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output encoding from PowerShell cmdlets is controlled by the $OutputEncoding variable, which is by default set to ASCII.
You can try to change it to say UTF8:

```
$OutputEncoding = [ System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
```

Answer (score 12):

Setting `$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` did not produce the right output characters for me.
Encoding the PowerShell script file as `UTF8-BOM` worked, without any further settings.

Comment: does not really answer, does it ?

Comment: You are right! It does not solve the general question of writing with arbitrary character encodings. However, it solved one important case for me: writing UTF8 characters.

Comment: @alfreds. but that was not what was requested?!